# Kerberos on C# Oracle Managed connection

Tags: c#, oracle, kerberos

Is there a way to set up a **Kerberos** authentication using a **Managed Data Access**?

We have a **C# application** which connects to our Oracle database for getting/inserting some data.

I have to implement a Kerberos authentication upon each user's connection to the Oracle database.

Following [this link](http://docs.oracle.com/database/122/ODPNT/featConnecting.htm#GUID-713B10C0-BC0B-4A37-833E-41E87FC980E6) I have managed to set up a Kerberos user on our DB. The rest of the steps are already implemented, as Oracle Client is Dropped on most of users' PCs. However, there are some users that don't have Oracle Client Dropped on their PCs, so I need to find a way to somehow set up those settings in the app.config.

sqlnet.ora file:

> SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES=(kerberos5pre)
>   SQLNET.KERBEROS5_CC_NAME=**** SQLNET.KERBEROS5_CONF=****
>   SQLNET.KERBEROS5_CONF_MIT=true
>   SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_KERBEROS5_SERVICE=oracle
>   SQLNET.FALLBACK_AUTHENTICATION=TRUE

and the krb5.conf file's settings:

> [libdefaults]
>   default_realm = *****
>   dns_lookup_realm = false
>   dns_lookup_kdc = true
>   passwd_check_s_address = false 
>   udp_preference_limit =
>   kdc_timesync =
>   [domain_realm]
>   ***** = ****

I have seen [this link](https://docs.oracle.com/database/122/ODPNT/InstallManagedConfig.htm#ODPNT8159) but I haven't managed to set up the right settings.

I have imagined it, something like this:

app.config:

```
  <oracle.unmanageddataaccess.client>
    <version number="*">
      <settings>
        <setting name="TraceOption" value="7"/>
        <setting name="PerformanceCounters" value="0"/>
        <setting name="SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES" value="kerberos5pre"/>
      </settings>
      <dataSources>
        <dataSource alias="SampleDataSource" descriptor="(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=ORCL))) "/>
      </dataSources>
    </version>
  </oracle.unmanageddataaccess.client>
```

And code:

```
string ProviderName = "Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client";

DbProviderFactory factory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(ProviderName);

DbDataSourceEnumerator dsenum = factory.CreateDataSourceEnumerator();
DataTable dt = dsenum.GetDataSources();
OracleConnectionStringBuilder csb = new OracleConnectionStringBuilder
{
    DataSource = (string)dt.Rows[1][1],
    Pooling = false 
};
_connectionString = csb.ToString();
_con = new OracleConnection(_connectionString);
_con.Open();
```

Answer (score 2):

The oracle managed driver expects has dependency with MIT Kerberos. section 3.3.7.2 from the [Shared Link](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/odpnt/featConnecting.html#GUID-D7175027-A087-449E-A400-02644BED56C2). Have you tried installing it on the client machine

Answer (score 0):

Managed ODP.NET supports only Kerberos5 and no pre version is supported.
Also please make sure it is 12.2 version:

SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES=(kerberos5)